# Sum total from multiple lists in one dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

very new to python and hope can get some help here. I'm trying to sum up the total from different lists in dictionary

```
{'1': [0, 2, 2, 0, 0], '2': [0, 1, 1, 0, 0], '3': [2, 4, 2, 0, 2]}
```

I have been trying to find a way to sum up the total as follow and append in a new list:

```
'1': [0, 2, 2, 0, 0]
'2': [0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
'3': [2, 4, 2, 0, 2]

0+0+2 = 2
2+1+4 = 7
2+1+2 = 5

[2, 7, 5, 0, 2]
```

I was able to get partial results for one row if I do this way but wasn't able ti figure out a way to get the output I want.

```
total_all = list()
    for x, result_total in result_all.items():
        new_total = (result_total[1])
        total_all.append((new_total))
    print(sum(total_all))

output 7
```

Any suggestions and help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `zip()` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)) function to transpose dictionary values and `sum()` to sum them inside list comprehension:

```
d = {'1': [0, 2, 2, 0, 0], '2': [0, 1, 1, 0, 0], '3': [2, 4, 2, 0, 2]}

out = [sum(i) for i in zip(*d.values())]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[2, 7, 5, 0, 2]
```

EDIT (little explanation):

The star-expression `*` inside `zip()` effectively unpacks dict values into this:

```
out = [sum(i) for i in zip([0, 2, 2, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [2, 4, 2, 0, 2])]
```

`zip()` iterates over each of it's argument:

```
1. iteration -> (0, 0, 2)    
2. iteration -> (2, 1, 4)
...
```

`sum()` does sum of these tuples:

```
1. iteration -> sum( (0, 0, 2) ) -> 2
2. iteration -> sum( (2, 1, 4) ) -> 7
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the help here and the detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

```
In [6]: list(map(sum,zip(*d.values())))                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[6]: [2, 7, 5, 0, 2]
```